# Separate panels variants for 'edit' & 'add' nodes of same type

Tags: panels, 7

[D7/Panels 3]

I have two different panels layouts - one for editing, the other for adding nodes of the same content type ("Contact Details").

A panel page for overriding 'edit' pages exists in Panels (in code), which I have activated. I've made a variant which works for 'edit' pages, but it is also overriding the 'add' page with the same layout.

I've added a context of 'Node add form' with 'Contact Details' as the 'Node type'. Also added a selection rule:

**Node: type / Node add form is type "Contact Details"**

Both forms still appear in the same panel layout (the one for 'edit' pages).

Help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String: URL path` in variant Selection Rule.

**Edit path:** `"node/*/edit"`

**New path:** use your content type path (`node/add/your-content-type`)